# tensorflow "adding an op" debugging?

Tags: tensorflow

I try to extend the tensorflow library: https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/adding_an_op

```
REGISTER_OP("Test")
.Input("input: string")
.Attr("test: float")
.Output("output: string")
.Doc(R"doc("some douc")doc");

class Test : public OpKernel {
 public:
  explicit Test(OpKernelConstruction* context) : OpKernel(context)
  {
    std::cout << "Why is this not printing" << std::endl;
    std::string input;
    OP_REQUIRES_OK(context, context->GetAttr("test", &input));
    std::cout << input << std::endl;
  }

  void Compute(OpKernelContext* context) override
  {
    std::cout << "Why is that not printing? " << std::endl;
    Tensor input_tensor = context->input(0);
    Tensor* output_tensor = nullptr;
    OP_REQUIRES_OK(context, context->allocate_output("output", 
    input_tensor.shape(), &output_tensor));
    auto output = output_tensor->flat<string>();
  }
};

REGISTER_KERNEL_BUILDER(Name("Test") \
                        .Device(DEVICE_CPU), \
                        Test);
```

Why is this function not printing? But I get an return value when I start the function. I think that it is not possible to print something, is not it?

---

Edit: How I call it in main.py?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.contrib.icg as tficg

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('start')
    print(tficg.stereo_matching('hello', 1))
```

Output:

```
start
Tensor("StereoMatching:0", dtype=string)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should print. Are you looking at stdout and stderr?

Comment: yes, for stdout and stderr. I need it for debugging.

Comment: So for some reason your op is not running. Can you show us the python code you're using to call this op? Can you add an exit(1) to this code to confirm it's running?

Comment: I edited it with my python test code and the output.

Comment: The code you wrote just creates an operation. You need to session.run(tficg.stereo_matching('hello', 1)) for the C++ code to execute.